# Google verify https://token.botframework.com/.auth/web/redirect as an unsafe URL

Tags: authentication, google-api, botframework

I am facing difficulties creating an integration between the google app and bot framework.

As part of our bot flow, users need to authenticate the bot connecting to their Gmail account, for which we created an app in Google and have defined the redirect URL as https://token.botframework.com/.auth/web/redirect.

Google identifies https://token.botframework.com/.auth/web/redirect as an unsafe URL and shows a warning to the user that the bot framework is not safe to connect,

Google recommends creating a subdomain for the redirect URL and confirming its ownership, but  I don’t know how to define a subdomain for  https://token.botframework.com/.auth/web/redirect.

Answer (score 0):

In order to connect your domain and use it as a redirect uri your going to have to register it in [Google search console](https://search.google.com/search-console/about)

Once its been registered you wont get that error any more

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply; Google Search Console validates only those domains I own. I do not own BotFramework. And I can't define a subdomain for it.